# How to display the contents that give rise to the sizes that `ls -l` reports for directories?

Tags: files, filesystems, directory

I understand that the sizes that `ls -l` reports for *directories* reflects the space taken up by the "metadata" for those directories.  Also, I imagine that this metadata exists in binary/non-human-readable form.

Is there a Unix command to display this metadata in human-readable form?

EDIT: if the answer to the question above is highly dependent on the filesystem, what keywords should I use to search for the answer for a particular filesystem?  (I'm interested in the answer for many types of filesystems, including nfs, ext3, ext4, vfat, gpfs, tmpfs, and lustre).  When I search for, e.g., "how to display directory data/information/contents", etc. I find only information on how to list the files in a directory, which is not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Other than `ls`?  That would depend on the type of file-system, and likely only used for debugging purposes by developers of device-drivers, etc.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: thanks; I've updated my question in response to your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` displays that information because the data is stored in the `size` field of the inode for the directory.  This is filesystem dependent.  A given filesystem could hold other information there.  As an example, ZFS reports the number of directory entries in that field.

If that's the level you're interested in, then reading the data is simple.  `ls` and `stat` are tools to display the inode information in different ways.  You can examine them to see how to pull the data and display it in human-readable form.  Take a look at [stat(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) for the system call to query the info.

If you just want to gather that number directly, consider `stat -c "%s"`

```
% ls -ld /
drwxr-xr-x 44 root root 4096 Jun 10 17:11 /
% stat -c "%s" /
4096
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: it's called `ls`…

The size reported by `ls` for a directory is the size of the directory contents. It isn't metadata of the directory, it's metadata of the files in the directory. Most of that is listed with `ls -la`.

On some Unix variants, you can display the binary form of that data by calling `cat` (or `od`, etc.) on the directory. This is not the case on Linux, and on systems where it's possible, the interpretation of that data may depend on the filesystem type or may be normalized (to be compatible with historical filesystem types). See [When did directories stop being readable as files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154119/when-did-directories-stop-being-readable-as-files) and [octal dump of directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264669/octal-dump-of-directory)

The size reported by `ls` is more than what it takes to store the data you see with `ls` for several reasons:

- There may be metadata that `ls` doesn't display, such as block lists for the file contents.
- There may be padding, e.g. unused bits here and there, alignment to machine word boundaries, file names stored in fixed-size fields, etc.
- There's metadata to organize the list of file names, e.g. a B-tree or search tree structure.
- Typically files are organized in blocks, and a file uses a whole number of blocks, with the last block being only partially filled unless the file size is exactly a multiple of the block size.
- On some filesystems, such as ext4, directories don't give back unused blocks after they've grown a lot (because they contained a lot of files) then shrunk a lot (because a lot of files were deleted).

If you want to know about things that `ls` won't show you, you need to go and look directly at the directory contents. Either run `od` or similar on the directory, if your Unix variant allows it, or use a low-level tool such as a hex viewer on the partition or a filesystem debugger such as [`debugfs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/debugfs.8.html) for ext2/ext3/ext4. The information you'll see in this way doesn't qualify as “human-readable” except to the very few people who are intimately familiar with the filesystem format.

Comment: No, it can't be `ls`.  `ls` does not tell me why two directories with exactly the same contents (one is an rsync copy of the other) but residing in different file systems have sub-directory entries whose sizes (according to `ls -ls`) vary widely (~10x) between the two filesystems.

Comment: @kjo, that's because the size of the directory (as kept in the inode) is not directly related to either the amount of data in subdirectories or the file structrure.  The file structure can influence it, but not guarantee anything.  Copying a directory (via `cp` or `rsync`) can often shrink it by removing stale directory entries.

Comment: @kjo Yes, it is `ls`. As I explain in my answer, there's space that contains metadata that you can only see with a filesystem debugger (and isn't human-readable unless you're deeply familiar with the filesystem format), and space that isn't used. If the sizes vary wildly, it can be because the filesystems store data in different formats, or because one of the directories contains more unused space.

Comment: @BowlOfRed: garbage-collectable items such as "stale directory entries" are *precisely* the kind of thing I want to look at.

Comment: @kjo, that data isn't public (or relevant in some cases).  Instead you need to go and walk the private structures.  Look at `debugfs`.  You can use that to dump a directory node and see the raw data inside.  Example: http://www.cs.montana.edu/courses/309/topics/4-disks/debugfs_example.html